# MySQL: Comparing the result of two convert functions

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Im currently working on a database that have been initialize with dates in varchar instead of using datetime format.
I'm supposed to compare the dates of the DB with an input date (31/05/2020 actually).

Here is the part of my code that makes troubles :

```
AND Convert(datetime,t1.fin_contrat, 103) > Convert(datetime, '31/05/2020', 103 )
```

But I've an error from PhpMyAdmin which is : #1064 - Syntax error near 't1.fin_contrat, 103) >= Convert(datetime, '31/05/2020', 103 ) GROUP BY siren  OR' line 1

According to this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#implicit-conversions varchar should be able to being converted directly to datetime value.
I tried to use WHERE instead of AND it doesn't work. So I'm out of option, and i'm seeking for ideas.
Thanks for your help

Comment: You have MySQL in the question title (which is consistent with the PHP usage), but the tag and the link imply SQL Server. What database are you actually using? And the full text of the query is going to be needed to debug a syntax error, one way or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you want something like this:

```
where date(t1.fin_contrat) = str_to_date('31/05/2020', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

This corresponds to the code in your question, but adapted for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The fonction `CONVERT` is not the same betweeen **Microsoft SQL**. and **Mysql**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

To convert a **string**. to a **date**. you must use `STR_TO_DATE`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

ps:

Every sql server software ( Oracle , Redshift , Posgtres , Mysql , MariaDB  , MS SQL server , Sqllite , ...)  has his own **SQL** dialect . Usually simple queries are portable but more complex or using functions queries must be rewriten .

Comment: Every brand of SQL database has it's own dialect. But every sql server, being a specific brand, uses the t-sql dialect of sql.

Comment: It's also sad to me how any supposed database developers don't even know what database they're using. You'll ask someone, and they'll say "Management Studio" or "PHPMyAdmin", and it's like hearing someone tell you they drive a "Sony" car because it's the brand on the stereo in your dashboard. :(

Comment: Thank you I was indeed using an other SQL dialect, as Im using MySQL STR_TO_DATE worked out, excuse me

Comment: Excuse me its MariaDB that my server is using, I did not created it.

Comment: MariaDB is a fork of Mysql FYI .